# Calling a method in javascript from onlick attribute of a html button

Tags: javascript

Im struggled now with JS again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ATM Interfacetest</title>
    <script>
        class Test{
            constructor(){
                this.name = 'heinz';
            }
            testwindow(){
                var tmp = document.createElement('button');
                tmp.id = 'idtest';
                tmp.className = 'test';
                tmp.onclick = this.test;
                tmp.innerHTML = 'Klick mich';
                document.body.appendChild(tmp);
            }
            test(){
            alert(this.name);
            }
        }
        function e(){
            var i = new Test();
            i.testwindow();
            // Testcall 
            i.test();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="e();">
</body>
</html>
```

Calling the method test from e() with onload in the body-tag works pretty fine.

Calling the method the button brought to the document, doesn't work. Reading out this.name is not possible. The alert-window remains empty.

As i am used to code like this from python, is JS following other principles?

Or how can i call the function from the button. At least it works fine, i can't get the issue by myself.

Calling

Comment: `this.onclick = this.test.bind(this);`

Comment: @Pointy I'm so glad. That was helpfull.